# Chrome background-color changing extension

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to chrome extensions. My target is to develop simple extensions that changes the page background color on load.
I have problem which you can see in the picture.

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf9RS.png)

[The Folder locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6i1F.png)

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Cool Extension",
  "version": "0.1"
}
"content_scripts": [
  {
  "css": [ "main.css" ],
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>",
    ],

    } 
]

      The Css



     *{background-color:black}
```

How to solve the problem, where is my problem?

Comment: Do you have a question? [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: 1) Replace `}` with `,` before "content_scripts", 2) remove `,` after the last `]`